# What is `linesize` in LibAV

Tags: c++, libavcodec, libav

I am playing with video encoding using LibAV and unable to understand the purpose of `linesize`.

For e.g., declaration of `av_image_alloc` function in LibAV takes linesizes as arguments:

```
int av_image_alloc  (   uint8_t *   pointers[4],
      int   linesizes[4],
      int   w,
      int   h,
      enum AVPixelFormat    pix_fmt,
      int   align 
   )
```

I am new to LibAV and video encoding. Feel free to provide any link which can also give me little background of video encoding.

Answer (score 2):

`linesize` is the width of your image in memory for each color channel. It may greater or equal to `w`, for memory alignment issue.

Check [ffmpeg av frame doc](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html#aa52bfc6605f6a3059a0c3226cc0f6567):

> For video the linesizes should be multiples of the CPUs alignment preference, this is 16 or 32 for modern desktop CPUs. Some code requires such alignment other code can be slower without correct alignment, for yet other it makes no difference.
>
> The linesize may be larger than the size of usable data – there may be extra padding present for performance reasons.

Comment: In case of RGB, linesize[0] will denote the size in bytes of each pixel for R color channel, linesize[1] will denote the size in bytes of each pixel for G color channel and so on right?

Comment: Quick Question, frame->data[0] contains the R channel and frame->data[1] contains G channel, right ?

Comment: @random_28 That would be true in case of planar RGB (such as `AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP`), however typically libav uses packed RGB, so `linesize[0]` will denote size in bytes for line in array of `RGBRGB...` bytes stored in `pointers[0]`. see `pixfmt.h` for the list of supported formats (which also explains how they are stored). Also note that this answer is rather misleading, `linesize` can be smaller or larger than `w` depending on pixel format while alignment is actually optional.

Comment: @VTT So pointers[0] contains all the `RGBRGB...` values. Then what are the `pointers[1]` and `pointers[2]` containing?

Comment: @random_28 nothing, they are supposed to be nulls when not used.

Comment: I am following this code, and here I see its trying to copy Cb and Cr in pointers[1] and pointers[2]. Look for comment "prepare dummy image" https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/encode_video_8c-example.html

Comment: @random_28 Well, that is because libav typically uses planar YCbCr. This case is described in my answer.

Comment: @random_28 I believe VTT has explained it well. There are lots of pixel formats following different layout combinations. You can check them in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/pixfmt.h.

Answer (score 2):

This function will allocate a buffer large enough to hold image data splitting it into one or more component arrays (planes). Depending on format, size of the line of the each picture component will have its own width (in bytes) (which may be much smaller or much larger than image width) and will also be padded to achieve the specified alignment (16 bytes typically to make vector instructions work). For example with typical YCbCr image with 4:2:0 subsampling there will be 3 planes (that is 3 non-null pointers stored in `pointers`) and width of the luma plane line will be (padded) image width, width of the each chroma component lines will be (padded) half image width.

Also note that both `pointers` and `linesizes` in this function are out pointer  parameters, not arrays.

Comment: It can’t be smaller than the width.

Comment: @szatmary I've mentioned an example when line size is 2x smaller than image width

Comment: Fair enough. The first half just reads funny, because you must have the chroma plane at least width size.

Comment: @szatmary Not really, chroma plane has 1/2 horizonal and vertical subsampling and each chroma line therefore is 2x smaller than image width...

Comment: I understand chroma sub sampling. On my first read of your response I felt it was less than clear. That’s ok if you disagree.

Comment: @szatmary I'm not sure where are you getting at, but at least now you understand that line width can be smaller than image width, right?

Comment: I have always understood that. I even knew the correct name, (“chroma sub sampleing”).

Comment: @szatmary Then why did write "It can’t be smaller than the width."?

Comment: Because even understanding the topic, as I read your answer it wasn't clear to me `Depending on format, size of the line of the each picture component will have its own width (in bytes) (which may be much smaller or much larger than image width)` Implies a format where all planes are less than width.

Comment: @szatmary While I'm not aware of such a format, it seems to be definitely possible (though weird).

Answer (score 0):

linesize array values are dependent on the pixel format. 
For NV12 pixel format each frame consists of two planes: Y plane and UV plane (U and V values are interleaved). Therefore `linesize[0] = frame_width` and `linesize[1]=frame_width` (due to subsampling the number of U-pixels=1/2 of luma pixels and the total number of U-pixels and V-pixels is frame_width).

For RGB24 pixel format each frame consists of single plane and `linesize[0]` os relevant only and `linesize[0] = 3*frame_width`